# Finding regex pattern of date on separate lines and between text

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I got the regex pattern of `15 July - 3 September 2022` as

```
[\d]{1,2} [ADFJMNOS]\w* [\-] [\d]{1,2} [ADFJMNOS]\w* [\d]{4}
```

My doubts are

1. What will be the regex pattern if the date is not on a single line

**example**

```
15 July - 3 September 
2022
22
July
```

**Desired Output**

```
15 July - 3 September 2022
22 July
```

2. Also if it is seen as a part of another word

**example**

```
delayed15 July – 3 Septemer 2022
```

Here it is attached with the word "delayed". The word can be anything.

**Desired Output**

```
15 July – 3 Septemer 2022
```

**Code i am trying**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url_list = ['https://alabamasymphony.org/event/bachmozart']

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.3"
}

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/ubuntu/selenium_drivers/chromedriver')
format_list = ["[\d]{1,2} [ADFJMNOS]\w* [\-] [\d]{1,2} [ADFJMNOS]\w* [\d]{4}"]
for URL in url_list:
    date = []
    driver.get(URL)
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    data = driver.page_source
    cleantext = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml").text
    cleanr = re.compile('<.*?>')
    x = re.sub(cleanr, ' ', cleantext)
    print(URL)
    for pattern in format_list:
        all_dates = re.findall(pattern, x)
        if all_dates == []:
            continue
        else:
            date.append(all_dates)
    for s in date:
        print(s)
```

Comment: without flags  `[ADFJMNOS]` will not capture lower case letters.

Comment: It is not really clear what you want - you do not show any code. SO is not a discussion forum, we tackle specific problems with specific solutions - you seem to have some grasp of regex, your last question(s) was also about regex - so what is your actual problem that you are trying to solve? nothing in your regex handles newlines in it ... and you are (at least) having 2 different problems here: newlines in text and text before number (wich is no real problem with the regex above) ... so ... what IS your specific problem.

Comment: I am trying to parse date from this https://www.gstaadmenuhinfestival.ch/en/program-and-tickets/concerts-2021/05-08-21-chamber-music. 
the data is cleaned and the from the cleaned data, i cannot parse the date. I will attach code now itself in the question part

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VWcGC8/1)):

```
(\d{1,2})\s*([A-Za-z]+)[ \t]*(?:(-\s*\d{1,2}\s*[A-Za-z]+)\s+(\d{4}))?
```

The idea is to break down the date and text in 4 groups and print those as needed by you.

source code ([run here](https://ideone.com/zOMZ2r)) :

```
import re

regex = r"(\d{1,2})\s*([A-Za-z]+)[ \t]*(?:(-\s*\d{1,2}\s*[A-Za-z]+)\s+(\d{4}))?"

test_str = ("15 July - 3 September 2022 as\n\n\n"
    "15 July - 3 September \n"
    "2022\n"
    "22\n"
    "July\n\n\n\n"
    "    Also if it is seen as a part of another word\n\n"
    "example\n\n"
    "delayed15 July - 3 Septemer 2022\n\n"
    "Here it is attached with the word \"delayed\". The word can be anything.\n\n\n")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for  match in matches:
    if match.group(3) is not None :
        print(match.group(1)+" "+match.group(2)+match.group(3)+" "+match.group(4))
    else:
        print(match.group(1)+" "+match.group(2))
```